# building and accessing list of arrays

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file with name, time slot, day

```
John, 10, day1
Smith,11,day1
Doe,10, day1
Isla, 12,day3
john,10,day4
john, 20,day4
```

I want to build an “attendance table” with the number of time I see someone in a time slot

```
Table[10] = [John,2],[Doe,1]
Table[11] = [smith,1]
Table[12] = [Isla,1]
Table[20] = [John,1]
```

So I have an array of size 24 which contains or not a list of unique names + occurrence
I’am new to python and I don’t know how to build this kind of array, if you can help me ?

Comment: Please, provide us with more information. What is `Table` meant to be? Is this some existing class? Are you supposed to design it? If the question is related to a certain framework within which this is obvious, please add corresponding tags. Also, if you've already tried something yourself it would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: Hello, table is a translation error,  It means array, I just wan to make (in memory) an array of names by time code, no framework or class also.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict
table = [defaultdict(int) for _ in range(24)]
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        name, hour, _ = line.split(',')
        name = name.strip().lower()
        hour = int(hour.strip())
        table[hour][name]+=1
for hour, entry in enumerate(table):
    if not entry:
        continue
    print("Table[{hour}] = {entries}".format(
        hour = hour,
        entries = str(','.join(["[{},{}]".format(name,occ) for name,occ in entry.items()]))
    ))
```

The output for your example will be:

```
Table[10] = [john,2],[doe,1]
Table[11] = [smith,1]
Table[12] = [isla,1]
Table[20] = [john,1]
```

Let me know if you need more explanations regarding the code.

Comment: hello, thank you a lot for this response, it works (but you already know) , I just have to study the (unknown by me) defaultdict, to really understand and "complicate" my code. 

If I may subsidiary question : can I store the (ie) id also: 
johnh,id,10,date -> Table[10][john,id,1], 

the print is for the moment very hard for me to understand
what is the more simple way to browse Table ? ie make a list off all (name,occurrence) for Table[10]
(I want to export it in csv using the csv fonctions)

thanks for your time ;)

Comment: I found the way to export the table as csv and access each element

Comment: Is your first comment still relevant?

Comment: hello yes in part :  can I store the (ie) id also: johnh,id,10,date -> Table[10][john,id,1],  thanks again